# How to automate sending Cloud Datastore entities to Elasticsearch VM on Google Cloud?

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to sync my cloud datastore with elasticsearch VM on Google Cloud. Whenever cloud datastore gets updated with a new record, a few fields of that should be sent to elasticsearch for indexing. I am using ELasticsearch by Bitnami VM on Compute Engine. After searching on the web, the most optimal solution seems using Pub/Sub and using Datastore to publish a message and my VM instance to subscribe to that topic. But I can't find any way to make Datastore publish a message (new record's contents) to Pub/Sub. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

If you think that Pub/Sub is not the right way to go about it, please feel free to suggest another way.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: How do your datastore entities get updated? The entity doing that is likely the 1st candidate to consider for triggering the transfers (the message publishing in pubsub case)

Comment: They get updated through Google Cloud Functions with http trigger. So, I can publish a message to a topic on PubSub in the same Cloud Function.But how do I make my elasticsearch compute engine instance subscribe to that topic? Should I use another cloud function with PubSub as a trigger or can I directly send the message's data to the VM?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with Elastic Search to answer that. I imagine that'd be the "subscribe" part of PubSub, but I have no clue how that's done on Elastic/Bitnami.